# How do you separate a nested method in a constructor to a separate method

Tags: java, android, function, methods, android-volley

This is more of a style thing, and a self-study thing, but In the volley code are listeners, and all the code I find online involve just nesting a override method inside the constructor. Not necessarily something I'm used to from a C# background. Actually not too great at lambda, anonymous methods neither.

I have no idea where to start, because it doesn't seem intuitive to me right now. But I'd like to separate out nested methods to their own respective methods. Or maybe even just the overridden methods if that is the only part that is needed.

```
    final EditText textView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = "http://myURL";

    JSONObject postparams = new JSONObject();
    postparams.put("city", "london");
    postparams.put("name", "bob");

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    JsonObjectRequest  postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, postparams,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    textView.setText("Success: "+ response.toString());
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    textView.setText(String.valueOf(error.networkResponse.statusCode));
                }
            }
    );
    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(postRequest);
```

What I would like is to name a method in the 2 Response arguments within the same class or maybe this itself to do the override. Is it possible? Something like.

```java
...
JsonObjectRequest  postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, postparams, myResponseListener(JSONObject response), myErrorResponseListener(VolleyError error));
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(postRequest);
}

public void myResponseListener(JSONObject response){
     textView.setText("Success: "+ response.toString());
}
public void myErrorResponseListener(VolleyError error){
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(error.networkResponse.statusCode));
}
```

Is there a simple way to something like this?

Edit: Trying linucksrox answer, to my surprise, the following actually stands alone as its own method... without a public(access modifier) or void(return type)??

```java
    Response.Listener<JSONObject> myListener(JSONObject response)
    {
        return new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                textView.setText("Success: "+ response.toString());
            }
        };
    }
```

But when I try to plug in myListener as the 4th argument, it complains about the arguments.

```java
myListener() no work, 
myListener(JSONOBject response) no work
```

The same is for the error section argument.

Comment: You could have the class itself implement the listener interfaces, or use method references.

Comment: Problem is, I don't know how to do that. It'd be cool if I could get an explanation on how to implement interfaces and method references, but I'm just as happy with example code that I can then try to pick apart and try to understand. Unfortunately those 2 phrases are just abstract words to me right now.

Comment: Have you looked into examples online? Implementing an interface is very basic - it's similar to extending a class. If you don't understand "extending a class", then you should really dig into these terms, as these terms apply to *many* languages. In your case, it would be `class YourClass implements Response.Listener<JSONObject>, Response.ErrorListener`. Doing this will force your class to implement those methods. From there, you would pass `this` to any areas that require the listeners: `new JsonObjectRequest(..., ..., ..., this, this);`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
    Response.Listener<JSONObject> myListener = new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            textView.setText("Success: "+ response.toString());
        }
    };

    Response.ErrorListener myErrorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(error.networkResponse.statusCode));
        }
    };

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    JsonObjectRequest  postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, postparams,
            myListener, myErrorListener);
```

Comment: comment formatted poorly, so I responded in the OP edited.

Comment: I just corrected the syntax verified in Android Studio that it compiles and runs fine for me.

Comment: Wow thanks! that worked! I think i sort of see it now. myListener is a object that holds an override method. So in the method we are not passing a method per-say but a Response.Listener object. Still sorta spins my head a bit. But sort of makes more sense now.

Comment: Exactly, myListener is an instance of a Listener<JSONObject> (which is actually an interface). That's what the JSONObjectRequest method definition asks for as a parameter. This is a common pattern (pass an instance of an interface into a method) which in a nutshell allows decoupling of classes so the receiving class doesn't need to know anything about the calling class.